# Add bits stream to buffer BYTE and write to binary file - C

Tags: c, binary

I'm trying to convert numbers to binary and then fwrite the binary numbers to binary file. 
Assuming all numbers are 7 bits numbers (int numbers < 127).
So in the end, the file will contain the numbers as blocks of 7 bits

I know that each BYTE is 8 bits, and i can't to write each number to 1 BYTE, but need to use the whole BYTE (i.e some of the numbers will be in 2 different BYTES)

if : 120 = 1111000  |   7 = 0000111  | 64 = 1000000

so the bit stream is 111100000001111000000 and should be written as

```
1111000|0 000111|10 00000|00
1BYTE     2BYTE      3BYTE
```

I thought to use a buffer 
shifting 8 bits to buffer and then fwrite to the file, using pointers 
But i just can't mange to write it. Thank you for your help

Comment: do you mean you want the file to contain "1111000" or "x" (the char for ascii 120)?

Comment: I don't understand you want write only 7 bits ? I think is impossible if char is not 7 bit in your OS.

Comment: @Stargateur: `char` cannot be 7 bits. A byte has at least 8 bits.

Comment: @Olaf Where did you read this ? Maybe in C, but a byte is the word machine. So a byte could be 7 bits on some machine.

Comment: @Stargateur: The C standard defines `char` being one byte; they are used synonymously. And the C tag indicates this is a C question. As a sidenote: any machine being able to run programs written in C **must** have at least 8 bits/byte; this results in a byte in the C language being the smallest addressable unit and from the min. required range of the three `char` types.

Comment: When newbies use the term "binary" it's often hard to know what they mean. char ch = 120 is already a binary 120, in one sense. In another sense, you need a string of at least 7 chars, with '0' and '1' the only characters allowed.

Comment: "Binary file" (as opposed to "text file") and "binary base" are different things.

Comment: Thanks all, This is an assignment and we need to write numbers (like 40, 120, 34 etc) as binary numbers into binary file. 

Meaning write the binary numbers by their bits to the file, and each binary number should take 7 bits.

Answer (score 2):

First, when dealing with bits use unsigned integers

```
unsigned char a = 0;
char bits[] = "1111000";
char *p = bits;
while (*p) {
    a <<= 1; // shift left
    a |= (*p == '1'); // add bit
    p++; // next bit
}
```

Comment: The operations will be done as `(signed) int` anyway!

Comment: Thank, and how do i write it into binary file?

Basically, i need to push bits (that represent numbers) into binary file

Comment: Do you want to compress the data? I mean: if you have `100` 7-bit values and write them to a file, the resulting file length should be 88 bytes (88 * 8 = 704 >= 100 * 7), "wasting 4 bits"? If not just write normally, "wasting" 1 bit for every value.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use the whole BYTE, cant write single number to singel BYTE

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to put 8 7-bit values in 7 8-bit locations

```
[-val-][-val-][-val-]...
00000001111111222222233333334444444555555566666667777777
[-loc8-][-loc8-][-loc8-]...
```

Just map bits and you're done

For example, the 3rd 7-bit value (assuming `int val7[8]`) can be written into the 8-bit locations (assuming `int loc8[7]`) with

```
loc8[1] &= 0xfc; // clear 2 bits
loc8[1] |= (val7[2] & 0x60) >> 5; // set 2 bits
loc8[2] &= 0x7; // clear 5 bits
loc8[2] |= (val7[2] & 0x1f) << 3; // set 5 bits
```